# SQL Server efficient sub-total in EF Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to achieve a query similar to this:

```
SELECT r.*, (SELECT COUNT(UserID) FROM RoleUsers ru WHERE ru.RoleId = r.Id) AS Assignments
FROM Roles r
```

To retrieve the number of the users per each role.

The simplest and the most straightforward option to implement desired output:

```
this.DbContext.Set<Role>().Include(x => x.RoleUser)
                .Select(x => new { x, Assignments = x.RoleUsers.Count() });
```

Retrieves all the roles, and then N queries to retrieve count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[RoleUsers] AS [r0]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [r0].[RoleId]
```

Which is not an option at all. I tried also to use `GroupJoin`, but it loads all the required data set in one query and performs grouping in memory:

```
    this.DbContext.Set<Role>().GroupJoin(this.DbContext.Set<RoleUser>(), role => role.Id,
        roleUser => roleUser.RoleId, (role, roleUser) => new
        {
            Role = role,
            Assignments = roleUser.Count()
        });
```

Generated query:

```
SELECT [role].[Id], [role].[CustomerId], [role].[CreateDate], [role].[Description], [role].[Mask], [role].[ModifyDate], [role].[Name], [assignment].[UserId], [assignment].[CustomerId], [assignment].[RoleId]
FROM [dbo].[Roles] AS [role]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[RoleUser] AS [assignment] ON [role].[Id] = [assignment].[RoleId]
ORDER BY [role].[Id]
```

Also, I was looking into a way, to use windowing functions, where I can just split count by partition and use distinct roles, but I have no idea how to wire up windowing function in EF:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*, COUNT(ra.UserID) OVER(PARTITION BY ru.RoleId)
FROM RoleUsers ru
    RIGHT JOIN Roles r ON r.Id = ru.RoleId
```

So, is there any way to avoid EntitySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is a defect in EF Core query aggregate translation to SQL when the query projection contains a whole entity, like

```
.Select(role => new { Role = role, ...}
```

The only workaround I'm aware of is to project to new entity (at least this is supported by EF Core) like

```
var query = this.DbContext.Set<Role>()
    .Select(role => new
    {
        Role = new Role { Id = role.Id, Name = role.Name, /* all other Role properies */ },
        Assignments = role.RoleUsers.Count()
    });
```

This translates to single SQL query. The drawback is that you have to manually project all entity properties.

Comment: I ended up with a single query, where `RoleUsers` comes from a `LEFT JOIN`, seems grouping still performs in memory. **UPD**: Actually it translates to the query I provided in my question.

Comment: If you find solution can you add it as answer? so that we also know what you did in order to fix the issue.

Comment: Well, seems you should materialize **EVERY SINGLE PROPERTY** to make this work, I was too lazy and mapped only an ID in my first comment. Thanks, @Ivan.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.DbContext.Set<Role>()
     .Select(x => new { x, Assignments = x.RoleUsers.Count() });
```

you dont need to add include for `RoleUser` since you are using Select statement. Furhtermore, I guess that you are using `LazyLoading` where this is expected behavior. If you use eager loading the result of your LINQ will run in one query.

you can use `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` before your LINQ query to disable lazy loading specifically for this operation

Comment: And you should open a bug report. If that is lazy loading, then this should not happen - there is no reason to go lazy loading if all that is asked for as a count.

Comment: Forgot to remove `Include` statement, my bad. Though, it changes nothing. Also, there is no lazy loading configured. *UPD*: From my point of view, lazy loading occurs when you request a data from a navigation property, when the query returned result and you have mapped entities, isn't it?